# SwiftUI artefact after detail with list is presented

Tags: swiftui

With the simple navigation-link structure below, I get a strange artefact after the detail view with a list is pushed on screen, as shown here https://youtu.be/LU9uluD5hEw.

If I include a section with a header, the view does not jerk up after the screen is loaded, but remains in its originally presented position. Anybody else experiencing this problem, or know how to fix it?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Link")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Master")
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Detail")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

This is especially annoying for picker details where I cannot add an empty section header as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:** It looks like a bug in TitleDisplayMode.large mode, because in the .inline mode such effect is not observed. So, the following might be considered as workaround if it is allowed by app design:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Detail")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail", displayMode: .inline)
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```